# string.Format is not giving correct output when INR currency symbol (Rs.) come to display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress

While display bank transaction data to INR currency symbol (Rs.), output is not coming correct way. I need to display currency symbol along with 2 decimal points with thousand separator.

I have tried so far<sup>1</sup>:

```
column.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = string.Format("{0} #,0.00", Model.CurrencySymbol);
```

I have used DevExpress MVC GridView.

Current output when INR Currency:

```
Rs2500. 00
```

Expected output when INR Currency:

```
Rs. 2,500.00
```

Its working fine for other currency, i.e. $ 1,500.00 or any currency.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Here `Model.CurrencySymbol` is type of `string`, i.e. "$" OR "Rs." etc, according to currency filter.</sup>

Comment: What is `Model.CurrencySymbol` type and it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Model.CurrencySymbol` string can have some symbols that can be interpreted as format specifier symbols.
You can use [literal string delimiter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) (`'string'`, `"string"`) so your currency symbol string will be copied to the result.
For example:

```
column.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = string.Format("'{0}' #,0.00", Model.CurrencySymbol);
                           //Here comes string delimiters: ↑   ↑
```

Also you can use escape character (`\`) to escape the dot symbol (`.`) in your `Model.CurrencySymbol`.
For example:

```
column.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = string.Format("{0} #,0.00", Model.CurrencySymbol.Replace(".", @"\."));
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I would not like hard-code to escape special character (here . (dot)), because, some reason, for any other currency symbol will not be treated by string.Format, I again need to hard-code. 

Your first one 'literal string delimiter' works fine and I think, it will be work in future also if any currency symbol come new or change.

Comment: @MihirShah So you can use string delimiters, as in my first example.

Comment: I applied string delimiters and it works fine for this scenario. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

just change your "Rs." symbol to "Rs\\." to escape "**.**"(to not include in numeric format).

Everything working fine on do this.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but I would not like hard-code to escape special character (here . (dot)), because, some reason, for any other currency symbol will not be treated by string.Format, I again need to hard-code.